# Bijection between cartesian products of sets to a given set of same total cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Came across this problem while solving a computer science problem. It smells of a math problem though. To rephrase the question in set terms lets say that for some positive integers k1, k2, ..., kn we have n sets {1,..,k1}, {1,..,k2}, ..., {1,..,kn}. Now the total number of elements across these n sets is k1*k2*...*kn lets call this M. We want to find a bijection between cartesian products of the above sets and the set {1, .., M}. Does such a bijection exist? Does it help if we know that n <= 5?

Comment: They have the same number of elements, so by definition there is such a bijection. This is the definition of "having the same number of elements" in set theory.

Comment: The total number of the elements belonging these $n$ sets is $k_1+k_2+...,+k_n$. The total number of the $n$-tuples (elements from different sets, the elements of the Cartesian product) is the product, M. There are a finite number of such $n$-tuples. So,...

Answer (score 1):

One certainly exists: just take a lexicographical ordering. If you want something a bit more explicit, then you could try a recursive formula. Name the $n$ sets $S_1, \ldots, S_n$. Define $\phi_1\colon S_1 \to \{1, \ldots, k_1\}$ by:
$$
\phi_1(x_1) = x_1
$$
Then for each $r \in \{2, \ldots, n\}$, define $\phi_r\colon S_1 \times \cdots \times S_r \to \{1, \ldots, k_1\ldots k_r\}$ by:
$$
\phi_r(x_1, \ldots, x_r) = k_r \cdot (\phi_{r-1}(x_1, \ldots, x_{r-1}) - 1) + x_r
$$
It can be shown via the Division Algorithm that $\phi_n$ is a bijection, as desired.